# Regex only resulting in last occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex string `/(.)(?:(.)(?!.*\2))+\1/g` is to find two characters with no repeated characters between them. For example, "aba" or "abcadea" are valid, whereas "abcba" is not valid because the b is present twice within the two a's. Essentially the a's are acting as a borders and no characters should be repeated within them.

The issue I am having is that its not correctly identifying all occurrences where this is happening. Take this example:

```
var s = "abababab";
s.match(/(.)(?:(.)(?!.*\2))+\1/g)
["bab"] //aba is also a valid occurrence

var s = "aba"
s.match(/(.)(?:(.)(?!.*\2))+\1/g)
["aba"] //it works on the string by itself
```

Another issue which I believe is related is its only finding the shortest match, so for example:

```
var s = "abcadefa";
s.match(/(.)(?:(.)(?!.*\2))+\1/g)
["abca"] //should also result abcadefa as a valid string
```

I cannot find where the bug is in my regex query. Any assistance would be great!

Comment: here are the regex debugger results, note the "explanation panel on the right, that breaks down each regex symbol.
http://regex101.com/r/sK4iY2/1  http://regex101.com/r/mA4oK5/1

Comment: So `TabcdeT` is valid but `TabcdeaT` is not because of the repeated `a` between the `T`'s?

Comment: The problem is the lookahead.
Whenever you have a repition it fails, which is correct but it does not stop at the `\1`. In the example `"abcadefa"` when it checks the 'a' in the middle it will find an 'a' at the end which is not allowed and backtrack to previous state

Comment: Another problem is that a string "abcdefaef" will only result in "faef" and since there are no repitions after the the first "f" the substring "abcdefa" which might be valid for you is discarded because when the engine checks "e" it will find a repition

Comment: So I think the major problem is that the lookahead is too greedy and does not stop at your `\1` which results in fails for the described cases